# Firebase cloud functions not finding woocommerce-rest-api package

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, woocommerce-rest-api

In my index.js I have included

```
const WooCommerceRestApi = require('@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api').default;
```

and in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
"@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.1"},
```

When doing `firebase deploy --only functions` I get the following error message:

```
npm ERR! Missing: @woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api@^1.0.1
```

The same dependency (also locally installed) is working fine in local enviroment but it's unable to be deployed to firebase cloud functions.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed changing

`woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.1"`  in package.json

with

```
woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": ""
```

Still to find out what package version it decides to use tho :-/